# Placing button at the bottom of container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

How can I create button like below,

[image]

Comment: What have you written yet?

Comment: @milt_on i don't get what you mean

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. used Stack widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for that

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: circleRadius / 2.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(
              16,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 2,
                  height: 2,
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 40,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: DecoratedBox(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Profile',
                style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

Comment: hey , please if i want to add a text inside the card, how can i go about it?

Comment: @Aniekan-abasiAkpakpan in which card white card?

Comment: yes i mean the white card

Comment: just add `Center(child: Text('OK'),),` in above your `Container` that was in `Column`

Comment: @Aniekan-abasiAkpakpan Most welcome Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text(
          "Profile",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code sample...change height according to your need...or use mediaquery for better result:

```
Container(
      height: 275,
      child: Stack(
      children: [
         Container(//container with background color
         height: 250,
         child: //other widgets
        ),
         Positioned(
         bottom: 0,
         child: //button here
        ),
      ],
    ),
 ),
```